# Create an ObservableCollection by filtering two ObservableCollections of the same type using LINQ and MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, observablecollection

I am attempting to create an ObserverableCollection to populate a grid view by viewing other collections and adding any object from the target collection that has different values from the source collection.

I have a model:

```
public class LayerModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string OnOff { get; set; }

    public string Freeze { get; set; }

    public string Color { get; set; }

    public string Linetype { get; set; }

    public string Lineweight { get; set; }

    public string Transparency { get; set; }

    public string Plot { get; set; }
}
```

And two ObservableCollections of that model in my viewmodel:

```
public ObservableCollection<LayerModel> SourceDrawingLayers { get; set; }

public ObservableCollection<LayerModel> TargetDrawingLayers { get; set; }
```

A collection for the conflicts:

```
public ObservableCollection<LayerModel> ConflictLayers {get; set;}
```

And lastly, a collection of target drawings to compare against:

```
ObservableCollection<TargetDrawingModel> TargetDrawings {get; set;}
```

In the application, the user is asked to select a source drawing. The user is prompted to an `OpenFileDialog` and selects a drawing file. At that point, `SourceDrawingLayers` is created from a method that looks at every layer in that file and creates the collection.

Next the user has to select a group of Target Drawings, represented by `TargetDrawingModel`. The selection is added to `TargetDrawings`.

Now the fun part.

I need open each Target Drawing and read the layers, then compare those layers against the SourceDrawingLayers and, if any property is different, I need to add it to `ConflictLayers`.

So far I have tried a nasty triple nested foreach statement that didn't work right so I started digging into LINQ since it seems like there's an easy solution to my problem but my results are strange.

This is where I'm at currently. I attempted to use a "where" statement looking only at the OnOff property inside my LayerModel but the resulting ConflictLayers ObservableCollection is simply populating with every layer inside of the TargetDrawing and displaying their settings as they are.

```
    private void PopulateConflictLayers()
    {
        foreach (TargetDrawingModel targetDrawingModel in TargetDrawings)
        {
            DataAccess da = new DataAccess();
            TargetDrawingLayers = da.GetDrawingLayers(targetDrawingModel.DrawingPath);
            ConflictLayers = TargetDrawingLayers.Where(y => SourceDrawingLayers.Any(z => z.OnOff == y.OnOff));
        }
    }
```

My goal is for `ConflictLayers` to be a collection of *only* the `LayerModel`s inside `TargetDrawingLayers`, where *any* property does not match what is in the `SourceDrawingLayers`.

I have also tried using the `Any` method but got the exact same result, where my `ConflictLayers` just diplayed every `LayerModel` inside my Target Drawing, regardless of the setting or whether it matched anything inside of `SourceDrawingLayers`.

Any ideas would be *hugely* appreciated!

Update: I tried the solution provided by reggaeguitar below and the result was my datagrid simply displayed all layers, unfiltered, in both the source drawing and the target drawing i added to the collection.

I implemented IEquatable on my `LayerModel`

```
 public bool Equals(LayerModel other)
    {
        if (other == null)
            return false;
        return
        Name == other.Name
        && OnOff == other.OnOff
        && Freeze == other.Freeze
        && Color == other.Color
        && Linetype == other.Linetype
        && Lineweight == other.Lineweight
        && Transparency == other.Transparency
        && Plot == other.Plot;
    }
```

And updated my method as follows:

```
 private void PopulateConflictLayers()
    {
        foreach (TargetDrawingModel targetDrawingModel in TargetDrawings)
        {
            DataAccess da = new DataAccess();
            TargetDrawingLayers = da.GetDrawingLayers(targetDrawingModel.DrawingPath);
            var s = TargetDrawingLayers.Except(SourceDrawingLayers).Union(SourceDrawingLayers.Except(TargetDrawingLayers));
            ObservableCollection<LayerModel> list = new ObservableCollection<LayerModel>(s);
            ConflictLayers = list;
        }
    }
```

Something I did wrong?

Comment: The Linq method Intersect might help you out. Make sure you implement IEquatable on the classes you're comparing

Comment: `ConflictLayers = TargetDrawingLayers.Except(SourceDrawingLayers)`

Comment: ConflictLayers = TargetDrawingLayers.Except(SourceDrawingLayers).Union(SourceDrawingLayers.Except(TargetDrawingLayers)

Comment: I tried reggaeguitar and Robert McKee's suggestions and didn't get quite the result. I've edited my question with the details.

Comment: Did you override GetHashCode too? That might be the issue

Comment: Try Robert McKee's suggestion, maybe you just need one Except call, I'm not sure exactly what differences you're trying to show.

Comment: Thanks reggaeguitar. I tried Roberts too but the result is the same. I get every layer from both SourceDrawings and TargetDrawings.

I did override GetHash

`public override int GetHaseCode()
{
 int PathHashCode = Path == null ? 0 : Path.GetHashCode();
//repeat for every property
return PathHashCode^ NameHashCode, etc...
}`

Comment: Maybe you want treat Name property as Id:
ConflictLayers = TargetDrawings.Where(td => !td.Equals(SourceDrawingLayers.Single(sd => sd.Name == td.Name)));

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that I want to post.

I ended up modifying my code as such:

```
ConflictLayers = TargetDrawingLayers.Where(i => !SourceDrawingLayers.Contains(i)).ToList();
```

I also implemented `IEquatable` on my `LayerModel` and overrode `GetHashCode()` on it as well. The result is my `ConflictLayers` is now correctly populated with `LayerModels` whose properties are different from `SourceDrawing`.

Comment: You declared ConflictLayers as ObservableCollection<LayerModel>. Note that when TargetDrawingLayers or SourceDrawingLayers collections is changed (add, remove, ...) ConflictLayers does't reflect that changes.